# Какой стандартный VCL контрол использовать для рисования рамок по сторонам?

Tags: delphi, vcl

Мне нужен стандартный VCL контрол, который бы позволял выбирать наличие, цвет и толщину рамок по 4 своим краям. TShape позволяет задавать рамку, но она "общая" для всех 4 сторон, а мне же нужны отдельно-конфигурируемые. Контрол нужен из стандартной поставки Delphi (т.е. чтобы не ставить всякие левые паки), и, желательно, по типу TShape (без стилизации при смене ОС / стиля оформления приложения. Т.е. чем проще, тем лучше).

Существует ли такой контрол в стандартном VCL? (спойлер: говорят что нет)

Каким образом такой контрол создать минимальной кровью? (т.е. не делать новый компонент, который придется ставить на все разработческие машины).

---

Что-то похожее предоставляет TPanel - можно ограниченно выбирать типы, толщины и стороны Bevel, но нельзя задать ни цвет, ни просто края (без эффекта "освещения").

TBevel - можно ограниченно выбирать стороны Bevel, но нельзя задать ни цвет, ни толщину.

*P.S. Знаю о создании своих контролов, но прежде чем бросаться писать свой велосипед, хотелось бы проверить наличие "штатного" способа.

P.P.S. Желательно именно контрол, а не способ для рисования на канвасе.*

Comment: ну так в чем проблема? берете TPanel, делаете его прозрачным и без рамки. На него ставите 4 TShape или TBevel (тут по вкусу), с помощью Align/Anchor прижимаете их по краям. Двум выставляете высоту, двум ширину. Готово. Теперь можно настраивать внешний вид. В извращенном варианте используется 9 TShape,

Comment: @KoVadim вот именно такой костылизации и хотелось бы избежать ;-)

Comment: идете дальше - ставите это на фрейм. А то пока выглядит хочу, что бы мне Борланд (да да, он самый) сделал компонент под мои нужды. И что бы был доступен с 1 версии делфи:)

Comment: @KoVadim не *"хочу чтобы сделал"*, а *"хочу узнать, существует ли из коробки"*. Накостылить то не проблема, но если этого можно избежать, то к чему плодить велосипеды? ) Например, не с первого раза узнал, что есть TSpinEdit, а согласитесь - он весьма удобен и "изкоробочен" )

Comment: нет, такого с коробки нет. Иначе Вы бы нашли уже.

Comment: @KoVadim можете запостить как ответ с предложенным способом реализации? Через день-два, если не будет других вариантов - приму )

Comment: постить костыль? м, это интересно.

Comment: `если не будет других вариантов` - а какой вариант ожидается? Ни в штатной поставке, ни в JVCL & AlphaControls & DevExpress компонентах такого нет. Так что максимально корректный (и максимально бесполезный) ответ на `нужен **стандартный** VCL контрол` - нет, такого нет :) Я бы не стал заморачиваться с 4 TShape на панели (чем больше контролов - тем хуже), проще перекрыть `procedure Paint`, это займёт 20 минут

Comment: @kami кстати, вариант с TImage тоже вполне хорош. (чтобы широкий контур можно было делать не строго внутрь, а "по границе"). Я же верно помню, что при перекрытии Paint рисовать можно будет только внутри "прямоугольника" контрола?

Comment: А в итоге-то что должно получиться? Просто 4 линии с разными характеристиками, или это должен быть полноценный контейнер, в который можно напихать другие контролы? А так - да, контрол должен предоставлять канву только в пределах своих координат

Comment: @kami в итоге нужен контрол у которого можно задавать наличие/толщину/цвет/стиль линий по 4 сторонам, причем линии эти по ребрам, то есть при толщине 4, они должны торчать на 2 внутрь и на 2 наружу (а еще лучше, настраиваться наружу/центр/внутрь). Для начала проверил - стандартного похожего ничего нет (кроме TBevel). Так что теперь буду писать свой "велосипед" =) Скорее всего, действительно, какого-нибудь наследника TPaintBox сделаю, с раздуванием размера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В дельфи есть стандартный компонент [TPaintBox](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TPaintBox) и у него есть стандартный метод OnPaint, в котором вы можете нарисовать всё что хотите, например так:

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
var
  PBox: TPaintBox absolute Sender;
begin
  with PBox.Canvas do
  begin
    MoveTo(0, 0);
    Pen.Color := clRed;
    LineTo(PBox.ClientWidth - 1, 0);
    Pen.Color := clTeal;
    LineTo(PBox.ClientWidth - 1, PBox.ClientHeight - 1);
    Pen.Color := clGreen;
    LineTo(0, PBox.ClientHeight - 1);
    Pen.Color := clNavy;
    LineTo(0, 0);
  end;
end;
```